# SSRS Filter Expression

Tags: reporting-services

I plot the chart from the below DataSet

```
Owner        Ver
A            1.1
A            1.2
A            1.3
B            1.1
B            1.2
C            1.1
```

In the chart, I need is an expression to filter A with 1.1 and B with 1.1 and 1.2 and rest 
Hence the data will have

```
Owner        Ver
A            1.1
B            1.1
B            1.2
C            1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you specifically need A = 1.1 and B in (1.1, 1.2)? Otherwise, you could use the minimum() operator to find your results. As it is, it looks as if you'll need to use WHERE logic for B, because otherwise you can't get the results you want.

The sticking point is that you want different logic for your Owner field, but the data doesn't support what you want to do. If you code in a PROC SQL command, you could use a CASE statement and force the results, but that's ultimately a poor design choice.

Answer (score 8):

For your specific requirement, you can set up a filter on the Chart like the following:

[image]

Where the expression is:

```
=IIf(
    (Fields!Owner.Value <> "A" and Fields!Owner.Value <> "B")
    or (Fields!Owner.Value = "A" and Fields!Ver.Value = 1.1)
    or (Fields!Owner.Value = "B" and Fields!Ver.Value = 1.1)
    or (Fields!Owner.Value = "B" and Fields!Ver.Value = 1.2)
  , "INCLUDE"
  , "EXCLUDE"
)
```

This gives your required results:

[image]

However, this is not scalable at all as you will have to make the expression more and more complex as more requirements exist - as mentioned in the other current answer it is probably worthwhile considering applying your filtering in stored procedure based on parameter inputs if possible.

But if you have very specific requirements the above should be fine.

**Edit after comment**

To explicitly exclude instead of include you can use exactly the same sort of thing, just flip the logic around.

Say you want to exclude the following combinations:

```
A -> 1.2
A -> 1.3
B -> 1.3
```

You'd just change the expression to the following:

```
=IIf(
    (Fields!Owner.Value = "A" and Fields!Ver.Value = 1.2)
    or (Fields!Owner.Value = "A" and Fields!Ver.Value = 1.3)
    or (Fields!Owner.Value = "B" and Fields!Ver.Value = 1.3)
  , "EXCLUDE"
  , "INCLUDE"
)
```

This gives the same results as above.

Comment: An excellent job showing the solution and discussing the scale issue. Many thanks!

Comment: This is cool, works like a charm.
What if I need to specify just the versions that needs to be excluded , that list is small compared to the the versions that are needed to be included . So exclude them if those versions are mentioned .

Comment: Glad it helped! I've added an example that might help with the other approach, i.e. explicitly exclude instead of exclude; it's the same principle, just change the logic in the expression as appropriate.